# Improving point within polygon calculations with python

Tags: python, performance, gis, shapefile, shapely

For my project in python I need to define to which country belongs a large number of coordinates (lat,lon). I have managed to do so using the shapely Point.within(Polygon) method (see code below), provided a shapefile of country borders downloaded from  [natural earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-0-countries/) (the shapefile must be split into singleparts polygons first, I didn't find how to handle multipart polygons properly).

Although the method works fine, it is a bit slow for making tons of queries. Probably that the performance is strongly linked to the shapefile resolution, however precision is needed. I have already done some progress with a bounding box pre-selection round (only polygons having the coordinate inside their bounding box are checked ) but I am trying to improve it further. How could I proceed ? I was thinking  to use an inner-bounding box to quickly discriminate unambiguous points, but then I don't know how to build them. Or maybe it is better to make once and for all some fancy lookup table ? I must say that I am not familiar with hash tables and alike, would it be an option ?

Thanks

```
#env python3
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
import shapefile

class CountryLoc:
    def __init__(self, shppath, alpha3pos = 1):
        polygon = shapefile.Reader(shppath)
        self.sbbox = [pol.bbox for pol in polygon.shapes()] 
        self.shapePoints = [pol.points for pol in polygon.shapes()]
        self.shapeCnames = [pol.record[alpha3pos] for pol in polygon.shapeRecords()] 
        self.shapecount = polygon.numRecords

    def which_country(self,lat,lon): 
        countries = self._pointcountry(lat,lon)
        if len(countries) > 1:
            print('too many countries at coord ({:.3f},{:.3f}) : {}'.format(lat,lon,countries)) 
        try:
            return countries[0]
        except:
            #print('no country ref @ latlon ({},{})'.format(lat,lon))
            return 'OXO'

    def _findBboxMatch(self,lat,lon):
        matchidslist = []
        for ids in range(self.shapecount):
            if lat >= self.sbbox[ids][1] and lat <= self.sbbox[ids][3]:
                if self.sbbox[ids][0] > self.sbbox[ids][2] :
                # rem RUS and USA BBOX are spanning accross the +180-180 cut 
                    if not(lon >= self.sbbox[ids][2] and lon <= self.sbbox[ids][0]):    
                        matchidslist.append(ids)            
                else:       
                    if lon >= self.sbbox[ids][0] and lon <= self.sbbox[ids][2]: 
                        matchidslist.append(ids)
        return matchidslist

    def _pointcountry(self,lat,lon):
        coord = Point(lon,lat)
        matchidlist = self._findBboxMatch(lat,lon) ## BBOX PRESELECT
        matchcountrylist = []
        for ids in matchidlist:
            pp = Polygon(self.shapePoints[ids])
            if coord.within(pp):
                matchcountrylist.append(self.shapeCnames[ids])
        return matchcountrylist

    def printCountry(self,lat,lon): 
        ctry = self.which_country(lat,lon)
        print('coord. ({},{}) is in {}'.format(lat,lon,ctry))
        bbmatch = self._findBboxMatch(lat,lon)
        print('matching BBOXs are {}'.format([self.shapeCnames[k] for k in bbmatch]))
        print(' ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # testing
    cc = input('lat,lon ? ')
    coords = [float(cc.split(',')[0]) , float(cc.split(',')[1])]
    coloc = CountryLoc('./borders_shapefile.shp', alpha3pos=9)
    coloc.printCountry(coords[0],coords[1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an acceleration structure, such as a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), a [spatial hash table](http://www.beosil.com/download/CollisionDetectionHashing_VMV03.pdf), and others.

When setting up your shape data, you'll load the structure based on where the shapes lie in the plane. With a quadtree, for instance, you recursively subdivide space into four quadrants until each leaf quadrant overlaps some small number of shapes (or none of them). Then you record a list of shape references at each of those leaves.

Later, when you're searching for the shape that overlaps a specific point, you traverse the tree of subdivisions based on just two comparison operations at each of about log *n* levels. When you reach the proper leaf quadrant, you need only check a small number of shapes with the `Point.within` function.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your advice. I am wondering, would a quadtree really be better than the bounding box method ? Because it already reduce quite efficiently the number of shapes to look into (2-3 max). It seems that a significant performance improvement would be to use the within method only in special cases like borders proximity, thus the inner bounding box idea which could in many cases avoid using ray cast algorithm.

Comment: I guess you probably only have 100-200 countries to check in total, so testing all bounding boxes every time is relatively cheap.

Comment: The inner bounding box idea is a good one, but that box will be tiny for some shapes. Better would be to have many boxes: to essentially rasterize the shape at some resolution. Each grid cell of the bounding box would say either "in," "out," or "border."

Comment: Good point, if I understand well a quadtree structure could in fact be used to build such a grid but with a dynamically sized resolution (rather than a constant grid resolution) and faster search capability than a full iteration. It didnt hit me at first but now it looks just perfect.